# Axios request using URL that includes a variable from a mapped collection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, get, axios

I don't think the title does a good job explaining this, so I'm sorry about that. Here's the quick summary. I have a collection that includes a key I need to pull out and append to a URL for an axios.get request. But, I need to map over the collection and make a get request for each key and return the results for each key.

If that doesn't make sense, maybe my terrible code will:

```
return this.props.wallets.map(wallet => {

  const apiLink = "https://api.smartbit.com.au/v1/blockchain/address/";
  const key = wallet.publicKey;
  const url = apiLink + key;
  this.getData = () => {
    axios
    .get(
      url
    )
    .then(res => {
      this.setState({ coins: res.data.address.total.received_int });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  };

  let totalBitcoin = this.state.coins/100000000;

    return (
      <tr key={wallet._id}>
        <td>
          <Link className="wallet-link" to={link}>
            {wallet.title}
            <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-stats" />
          </Link>
        </td>
        <td>
          {totalBitcoin}
        </td>
        <td>
          <Link to="/wallets/delete">
            <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" />
          </Link>
        </td>
      </tr>
  );
});
```

`getData` is a function that makes sure I'm only making the get request at a predetermined interval.

So, this almost works. I get the data back, sets all instances in my table of the `totalBitcoin` variable with the same result. Then it constantly updates that value as the function maps through my collection.

I have no idea how to make this axios request without mapping over my collection to get the necessary variable for the endpoint I'm calling. And I have no idea how to properly set my mapped variable. Any help would be so appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are invoking `this.setState` method inside every iteration of `this.props.wallets.map`, `this.state.coins` value is constantly being reseted to a new value upon every axios request resolvement. This seems useless.
Also the variable `totalBitcoin` will always be equal to the last resolved wallet's axios response `res.data.address.total.received_int`.

You could do the API calls in the `componentDidMount()`, then append each wallet response to the `this.wallets` array like so `this.setState({wallets: [...this.state.wallets, wallet]})`.
Now in the render function you can do `return.this.state.wallet.map(wallet => ...)`;

Example

```
  class WalletContainer extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount(){
      this.props.wallets.map(wallet => {
        const apiLink ="https://api.smartbit.com.au/v1/blockchain/address/";
        const key = wallet.publicKey;
        const url = apiLink + key;
        this.getData = () => {
          axios
          .get(
            url
          )
          .then(res => {
            const newWallet = { 
                id: wallet._id,
                title: wallet.title,
                coins: res.data.address.total.received_int
            }
            this.setState({ wallets:
              [...this.state.wallets, newWallet]
             });
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
          });
        };
      })
    }
    render(){
      return this.state.wallets.map(wallet => {
        const totalBitcoin = wallet/100000000; // should be const because it never changes
        return (
          <tr key={wallet.id}>
            <td>
              <Link className="wallet-link" to={link}>
                {wallet.title}
                <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-stats" />
              </Link>
            </td>
            <td>
              {totalBitcoin}
            </td>
            <td>
              <Link to="/wallets/delete">
                <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" />
              </Link>
            </td>
          </tr>
        );
      })
    }

  }
```

in case it's possible for props to change, you should write additional logic in `willRecieveProps()` where you will do the axios request and append the new wallet to the `this.state.wallets` or remove a wallet that is not present in the new props.

Comment: Ante, this makes a ton of sense! Thank you for the help.

Comment: @JustinHunter I updated the example, I forgot to concat the `this.state.wallets`, now it should be okay. Also, if this solves your problem make sure you mark the answer as correct.

Comment: Quick follow-up: I can get the data to render properly only by switching from this page to another then switching back within the app. I've tried moving the API call to componentWillMount thinking it was a mounting issue, but I get the same problem. Any thoughts?

Comment: "componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is mounted" - [componentDidMount() documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reactcomponent.html#componentdidmount).

                                                                                                                   
Put your new code on repl.it or somewhere so I can take a look

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I'm beating my head against the wall on this whole thing. Here's a link to the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/pjo6qxxn6j
When the editor loads up, open the Wallets file on the left to view.

Comment: What does `this.props.fetchWallets()` do? Does invoking this function causes `WalletContainer` to recieve these props `this.props.wallets`. If so, the problem is very simple. When `WalletContainer` is being mounted,  `this.props.wallets` will be empty  because `this.fetchData() was not called and resolved yet`. This could be solved by moving your API calls to the [componentWillRecieveProps(newProps)](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) which is invoked every time props change (e.g wallets are passed down to the component).

Comment: Maybe a cleanear approach would be to call `fetchData()` in the parent component and then when you have the wallets you can render the WalletContainer.

Comment: You are the man! You are spot on! It's working now and I would have spent another week or more trying to figure this out without your help. Thank you very much!